# Relational tables best practice

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

im building a application where will run a mysql database, and in the database i will have some relational tables, but latelly i been looking different relational tables online different of how im used to do, basically i dont no what is the best practise and hope in finding the best way to go, above i leave a small example of how i normally do and other online examples:

My practice:

```
users
- id
- role_id;
- email
- password


roles:
- id
- title
```

Online Example from others

```
users
- id
- email
- password

role_user:
- role_id
- user_id

roles:
- id
- title
```

Basically my question is wich one is better, in terms of best practise and scalability?

Comment: Not a good question for here but the schemas are fundamentally different, the second one allows for multiple roles per user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on if you want a many-to-many or a one-to-many relationship. In your first example, that's a one-to-many relationship. In other words, a user can have at most one role. In the second example, users can have many roles and roles can apply to many users.

So, if you need users to be in more than one role, use the second example. Otherwise, your first example is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

the second is normally used when  you need a separated module for rbac functionality .. in this way the aspcted related to the role are not intrinsecally related to the user authentication  module..

Your solution is formally correct butn don't keep in the right consideration the design aspctec of keep the modules separated ..

Answer (score 0):

In Simple words, if you think that one user gonna have multiple roles, then 'role_id' column of 'users' table in become insufficient, so, if are you pretty sure that one user will have only one role anyhow, then first one is fine

else go with second one!